# Activity switch crash

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, switch-statement

I have a problem with switching between two activities.
My application always crashes, when I click on the login button.

The main activity is openAc, and the other one is login.

Here is my source code.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class openAc extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open);

        setupMessageButton();
    }

    public void loginAc(){
        startActivity(new Intent(openAc.this,login.class));
    }
    public void setupMessageButton(){
        Button messageButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(openAc.this,login.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the other class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class login extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

Comment: You add activity in manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare your login activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".login" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```